# Handle JavaFX popup in selenium

Tags: selenium, popup

When i click on patient ,i will get a JavaFX popup .How can i handle the same using selenium?
I have to check the title and click on OK

When i add the driver to watch list
i am doing 
`fxdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("text[text*='discharged']").getText()` - return nothing

I just cant inspect the same and i have created a `fxdriver` which handles the page but when the popup comes out i cant do anything with the application (application freezes out) until i click on OK in the popup

Comment: can you share the more information about this..

Comment: I will have a patient ,when i click on patient an Java FX popup is coming out (Not an HTML popup) .When the popup comes out i cant access application untill i click on OK or close in that popup.i will not have a control on the application.(Cannot move the popup as well). So my driver will not able to interact with the popup object or the application. when i close the popup i am getting my driver instance.

Comment: so does the popup comes across the same activity or any time it comes means at particular position or at any time it's showed up